# вопрос по classList.toggle

Tags: javascript

как сделать что бы при нажатии  на div с классом test у элемента c айди test убирался  класс foo если он был до этого установлен , и если нажать 
на элемент с классом test-2 то класс foo в элементе #test удалиться , но у div  с классом test установлен onclick по этому не удаляется класс foo у #test,
 можно было бы написать классу .test при клие test.classList.remove("foo") но новые  элементы могут быть добавлены динамически

```js
var h = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
 h[0].onclick = function(e){
   this.classList.toggle("foo");
   e.stopPropagation();
   
  }
    
 
 document.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 e = e.target;
 while(e)
  if (e == test)
   return
  else
   e = e.parentNode;
 test.classList.remove("foo");
});

test.addEventListener("click",function(){
 this.classList.toggle("foo");
});
```

```css
#test{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #000;
   transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .test{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #000;
   transition: 0.4s;
      margin: 10px;
  }
    .test-2{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #000;
   transition: 0.4s;
  }

  /*script interaction*/
  .foo{
   width: 400px !important;
   height: 400px !important;
   background: red !important;
  }
```

```html
<!-- div id test and add dynamic class toggle -> foo -->
 <div id="test"></div>
 
 <div class="test"></div>
 <div class="test-2"></div>
```

Comment: «при нажатии не на этот элемент» — а при нажатии на куда?

Comment: @andreymal при клике на боди либо другой любой элемент , нужно как то сделать что бы он определял что кликнули не по нему

Comment: @coffeehoock, элемент никак не может узнать, что кликнули _не_ по нему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 e = e.target;
 while(e)
  if (e == test)
   return
  else
   e = e.parentNode;
 test.classList.remove("foo");
});

test.addEventListener("click",function(){
 this.classList.add("foo");
});
```

```css
#test {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #000;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

.foo {
 width: 400px !important;
 height: 400px !important;
 background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: хотелось бы что бы ещё и при клике на элемент test тоже добавлялся класс foo и при клике на другой элемент класс foo удалялся причем при клике на любой элемент div  так как не известно сколько этих элементов там еше будет

Comment: да верно обычно так делают для меню выпадающих происходит клик и элемент тест понимает что клик был не на нем и удаляеться класс foo если он был добавлен

Comment: @coffeehoock обновил код

Comment: почти то что надо , единственное что при клики на другой див у которого тоже есть онклик , тест не удаляет класс foo

Comment: внёс правки. всё никак не даёт покоя вопрос, почему всего этого не было в вопросе и приходится вносить тысячу правок? для решения дополнительных вопросов нужно создавать новые или отредактировать свой вопрос в полной мере, а не поэтапно после каждой правки

Comment: не ожидал что так получиться думаю нужно открывать другой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Можно навесить обработчик на `document` с помощью `addEventListener`, передав третьим параметром `useCapture=true`, чтобы таким образом перехватывать все события внутри дерева, а в обработчике выполнять проверку.

Пример:

```js
function listener(e) {
  if (e.target != test) {
    test.classList.remove('foo');
  } else {
    test.classList.add('foo');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', listener, true);
```

```css
#test {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #000;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

/*script interaction*/
.foo {
 width: 400px !important;
 height: 400px !important;
 background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- div id test and add dynamic class toggle -> foo -->
 <div id="test"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```